# In Node JS, how to cast a hash value as a uuid equal to TSQL's Cast As Uniqueidentifier

Tags: node.js, t-sql, uuid

We have a process creating uuid's in TSQL using the following:

`SELECT Cast( HASHBYTES('MD5', 'some string') as uniqueidentifier)`

I created an API in node js, and they want me to be able to create the same unique identifier off of 'some string'. Is that possible? Using crypto, I can get the same hex value as the HASHBYTES command (`crypto.createHash('md5').update('some string').digest("hex")`), but I don't know how I would convert it to the same uuid that TSQL is returning.

I believe what I want is a v3 uuid, but I don't know what the namespace would be. I thought maybe SSMS was using some value specific to the server to create the uuid, but I was able to get the same value on three different servers, two on our network and another on a random EC2 instance.

Am I misunderstanding something very basic about uuid's? Or is there some namespace specific to Microsoft SQL Server, consistent between all servers?

Node libraries I've checked out: uuid,
uuid-1345,
uuid-lib,
guid

I've also tried the aguid library, which seems to do what I want but in SHA256. I borrowed the code and switched it to md5, but then I saw that all that library is doing is taking a hash and adding a 4 or 8 at certain character indices.

Answer (score 0):

A friend figured out how TSQL handles cast as uniqueidentifier. They just rearrange the characters of the hash! Here's how you'd do it in Javascript:

```
var castAsUuid = function(str){ var x = str.substring(6, 8) + str.substring(4, 6) + str.substring(2, 4) + str.substring(0, 2) + '-' + str.substring(10, 12) + str.substring(8, 10) + '-' + str.substring(14, 16) + str.substring(12, 14) + '-' + str.substring(16, 20) + '-' + str.substring(20, 32)
```

return x.toUpperCase()
}

They seem to be doing it the same way every time (tried about ten different strings). Good times.